# MvvmCross Custom IoC Integration breaks Plugin Registration

Tags: mvvmcross, tinyioc

I'm trying to integrate TinyIoc with MvvmCross. I followed the instructions from 
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup#changing-the-ioc-container-that-mvvmcross-uses

and created an adapter

```
public class TinyIoCMvxIoCAdapter : MvxSingleton<IMvxIoCProvider>, IMvxIoCProvider
{
  ...
}
```

that implements all the methods and forwards it to the TinyIoC container. That was very straight forwared and I only had to implement some additional code to fire the callbacks when something gets subscribed for

```
void CallbackWhenRegistered<T>(Action action)
void CallbackWhenRegistered(Type type, Action action)
```

I changed Setup.cs

```
    protected override IMvxIoCProvider CreateIocProvider()
    {
        var provider = TinyIoCAdapterSetup.CreateIocProvider();
        return provider;
    }
```

with

```
 public class TinyIoCAdapterSetup
 {
    public static  IMvxIoCProvider CreateIocProvider()
    {
        var container = TinyIoCContainer.Current;
        container.AutoRegister(t => t == typeof(IMvxViewModel));
        return new TinyIoCMvxIoCAdapter(container);
    }
}
```

That all works great. I can see that register is called on TinyIoc and things are getting resovled as well.

What does not work are the plugins. We are using the Messenger plugin and with the TinyIoC integration, the IMvxMessenger cannot be resolved when a ViewModel is resolved that gets the IMvxMessenger ctor injected. I can see that the MessengerPluginBootstrap is created by Mvx but I couldn't see that a call was made to register IMvxMessenger.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each plugin has a `PluginLoader` class that the `Bootstrapper` calls to register the plugin in the IoC container.

It looks something like this:

```
public class PluginLoader
    : IMvxPluginLoader
{
    public static readonly PluginLoader Instance = new PluginLoader();

    private bool _loaded;

    public void EnsureLoaded()
    {
        if (_loaded)
        {
            return;
        }

        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxMessenger>(new MvxMessengerHub());
        _loaded = true;
    }
}
```

Without seeing your IoC adapter, it's difficult to say what the issue is. Try manually registering the plugin to see if the IoC container is working properly.

Comment: This answer is spot on the money.... the plug bootstrappers rely on `CallbackWhenRegistered` to do their work - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/1ec7bc5f0307595c7ae11f56727dd0e9d2a2262f/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/Plugins/MvxPluginBootstrapAction.cs#L17 Without `CallbackWhenRegistered`  you will need to find another way to do the bootstrapping - probably using "old skool" techniques like `EnsureInitialized` calls on each plugin.

Comment: How/When is the IMvxPluginManager registered? Is the SimpleIoCContainer doing an auto register for all the Mvx types? I can see that something is trying to resolve the IMvxPluginManager before Setup.CreatePluginManager is called and it failes because it is not registered yet.

Comment: I fixed my implemenation of CallbackWhenRegistered and everything is working. Thanks for pointing me the right direction. MvvmCross is awesome!

Comment: Is there any possibility that you could provide the sources of your integration? Cause I would like to use TinyIoC as well as it supports injection of IEnumerables